# How to code a command for a discord bot in python for searching up images by tags

Tags: discord.py

I'm making my own discord bot while i'm learning python (just started learning 2 days ago) and i've been watching tutorial videoes on how to do everything i need to do to make my bot. I've learned how to make some basic commands with kicking or banning or showing info about people. One thing i do want to do with this bot is have it search of images with a tag and post them like: !img Pokemon, the bot would post a random pokemon picture it finds on the internet or a website more specificly would be better.

This is for my personal discord servers and I don't know where to even start on this.

It should take a tag and search a website for a image with that tag and post it.

Comment: Take a look at the [Imgur API](https://apidocs.imgur.com/#3c981acf-47aa-488f-b068-269f65aee3ce)

Comment: Posting code in the screenshot doesn't help. Check out [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm looking at that and im confused about what it says, sorry im new to python if you could help explain then ill be grateful.